# how to customize background color for mat-form-field?

Tags: angular, mdc-components

All mdc mat-form-field examples have gray/whitesmoke background. How can I change it?

https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Answer (score 2):

Angular 15 and greater below property in root styles.css allows to control the background of text fields

```
/* Angular 15 adds grey background on mat form components */
/* below removes that background color */
/* Manipulate initial background color*/
  .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
     background-color: transparent !important;
 }
/*Manipulate background color on hover and focus*/
 .mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay {
       background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: angular v17 removed legacy styles, and this change works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following. Wondering if there is a better way:

```
.mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
    background-color: white !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

.mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can  try

```
.mat-form-field {
 background-color: #b0e0e6; /* Light blue color */
}
```

or

```
.mat-mdc-form-field {
 background-color: #b0e0e6; /* Light blue color */
}
```

in your styles.css

Comment: Does nothing for mdc

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/munw8f?file=src%2Fexample%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html